# XAMPP issue? Code isn't changing after save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xampp

I'm using XAMPP as a test server for this game I'm trying to make. It's been working fine for awhile. Now, all of a sudden, when I change a file in Notepad++ and save it again, the changes aren't reflected on localhost. It isn't all files, either, just some of them.

For example, I can add random letters or screen outputs into some files, and they'll show up onscreen, but in other files they revert back to the way the file was before I changed it.

I'm coding in HTML, CSS, Javascript/Jquery, and PHP. This issue is showing up in some of the HTML and JS/query files.

Please help!

Comment: Try `Ctrl+F5` in your browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable caching in your browser, if enabled.

Disable caching in your server, if enabled.

If it's a default XAMPP installation I guess disabling caching in browser is enough.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.